# tab layout inside tab layout not rendering sometimes

Tags: android, android-tablayout

For a little school project me and a couple fellow students are marking an android app.
We decided using tab layout on our main activity, and ended up needing and extra tab layout inside one of the main tabs, both tab layouts have 3 tabs each.
The first 2 tabs of the inner tab layout fail to render sometimes.
Below is some of the code that might be relevant, if more information is needed I'll gladly add it.

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    ...
}
```

MiddleTabFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container2);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs2);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    ...
}
```

Both View Pagers look like this (different id):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated, i searched a lot and couldn't find this issue.

Comment: If they fail to render, is there any error message?

Comment: Not that i can see, i've looked all over the Logcat and it seems to feed the same information as usual